# How to store Dataframe data to Firebase Storage?

Tags: python, pandas, firebase, dataframe

Given a pandas Dataframe which contains some data, what is the best to store this data to Firebase?

Should I convert the Dataframe to a local file (e.g. .csv, .txt) and then upload it on Firebase Storage, or is it also possible to directly store the pandas Dataframe without conversion? Or are there better best practices?

**Update 01/03** - So far I've come with this solution, which requires writing a csv file locally, then reading it in and uploading it and then deleting the local file. I doubt however that this is the most efficient method, thus I would like to know if it can be done better and quicker?

```
import os
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db, storage

cred   = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(cert_json)
app    = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, config)
bucket = storage.bucket(app=app)

def upload_df(df, data_id):
    """
    Upload a Dataframe as a csv to Firebase Storage
    :return: storage_ref
    """

    # Storage location + extension
    storage_ref = data_id + ".csv"

    # Store locally
    df.to_csv(data_id)

    # Upload to Firebase Storage
    blob    = bucket.blob(storage_ref)
    with open(data_id,'rb') as local_file:
        blob.upload_from_file(local_file)

    # Delete locally
    os.remove(data_id)

    return storage_ref
```

Comment: Do you want to query it or just store the file? If you want to perform queries on the data then you need to obey the Firebase database data types.

Comment: No query just to retrieve the data again as a dataframe

Comment: Have tried using this https://pypi.org/project/python-firebase/. I think you have to write a custom script.

Comment: I don't think firebase is appropriate for a tabular data structure but the best way I can think of is to use `to_json` method of the DataFrame with `orient='records'` and save each row as a document. If it's a small table you can also use `orient='table'` which stores meta data (data types etc.) as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [python-firebase](https://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/) and [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
postdata = my_df.to_dict()

# Assumes any auth/headers you need are already taken care of.
result = firebase.post('/my_endpoint', postdata, {'print': 'pretty'})
print(result)
# Snapshot info
```

You can get the data back using the snapshot info and endpoint, and reestablish the `df` with `from_dict()`. You could adapt this solution to `SQL` and `JSON` solutions, which `pandas` also has support for.

Alternatively and depending on where you script executes from, you might consider treating firebase as a db and using the dbapi from `firebase_admin` (check [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/07/accessing-database-from-python-admin-sdk.html) out.)

As for whether it's according to best practice, it's difficult to say without knowing anything about your use case.

Comment: You assume its better to store it to Firebase instead of Firebase Storage?

Comment: You mean firebase db vs firebase storage? Again that's more specific to your use case

Comment: My question relates to Firebase Storage not the DB as in your answer.

Comment: My answer was for firebase storage AND suggested a firebase DB alternative

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to reduce code length and the steps of creating and deleting files, you can use `upload_from_string`:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db, storage

cred   = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(cert_json)
app    = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, config)
bucket = storage.bucket(app=app)

def upload_df(df, data_id):
    """
    Upload a Dataframe as a csv to Firebase Storage
    :return: storage_ref
    """
    storage_ref = data_id + '.csv'
    blob = bucket.blob(storage_ref)
    blob.upload_from_string(df.to_csv())

    return storage_ref
```

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_string

Answer (score 1):

After figuring out for hours, the following solution works for me. You need to convert your csv file to bytes & then upload it.

```
import pyrebase
import pandas

firebaseConfig = {
   "apiKey": "xxxxx",
   "authDomain": "xxxxx",
   "projectId": "xxxxx",
   "storageBucket": "xxxxx",
   "messagingSenderId": "xxxxx",
   "appId": "xxxxx",
   "databaseURL":"xxxxx"
};

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebaseConfig)

storage = firebase.storage()

df = pd.read_csv("/content/Future Prices.csv")

# here is the magic. Convert your csv file to bytes and then upload it
df_string = df.to_csv(index=False)
db_bytes = bytes(df_string, 'utf8')

fileName = "Future Prices.csv"

storage.child("predictions/" + fileName).put(db_bytes)
```

That's all Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I found that starting from very modest size of dataframe (below 100KB!), and certainly for bigger ones, it's paying off to compress the data before storing. It does not have to be a dataframe, but it can be any onject (e.g. a dictionary). I used pickle below to compress. Your object can be seen on the usual firebase storage this way, and you get gains in memory and speed, both when writing and when reading, compared to uncompressed storage. For big objects it's also worth adding timeout for to avoid ConnectionError after the default timeout of 60 seconds.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, initialize_app, storage
import pickle

cred = credentials.Certificate(json_cert_file)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {'storageBucket': 'YOUR_storageBucket (without gs://)'})
bucket = storage.bucket()

file_name = data_id + ".pkl"
blob = bucket.blob(file_name)

# write df to storage
blob.upload_from_string(pickle.dumps(df, timeout=300))

# read df from storage
df = pickle.loads(blob.download_as_string(timeout=300))
```