# Getting error when trying to write to firebase (firestore) with R

Tags: r, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the package Kohze/fireData to upload and download .txt documents to/from Firebase.
The package can be found here: https://github.com/Kohze/fireData
The function descriptions can be found here: https://github.com/Kohze/fireData/blob/master/R/index.R

When I upload a file the response should be “directory/filename”, but when I try to upload a file I get a response of “directory/“, and am not able to locate or download the file, so I think that my files are not uploading properly. Do you have any idea why this would be the case and how I could fix it?

I am getting an error saying Error 404
redirect_uri_mismatch

Here is the code

```
upload <- function(x, projectURL, directory = “main”, token = “none”){
  output = fileConversion(x)
  if (token == “none”) {
    Response = httr::POST(paste0(projectURL,“/”,directory,“.json”), body = jsonlite::toJSON(output, auto_unbox = TRUE))
  } else {
    Response = httr::POST(paste0(projectURL,“/”,directory,“.json?auth=“,token), body = jsonlite::toJSON(output, auto_unbox = TRUE))
  }
  return(paste0(directory,“/”,httr::content(Response)$name))
}
download <- function(projectURL, fileName, secretKey = “none”, token = “none”, isClass = FALSE) {
  if (secretKey == “none” && token == “none”) {
             urlPath = paste0(projectURL,“/”,fileName,“.json”)
        } else if (token != “none”) {
             urlPath = paste0(projectURL,“/”,fileName,“.json?auth=“,token)
        } else {
             urlPath = paste0(projectURL,“/”,fileName,“.json?auth=“,secretKey)  }
        data = httr::GET(urlPath)
        if (is.null(jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(data,“text”))))
              warning(“No data found at database location.“)
         if (isClass) {
              retrievedData = httr::content(data,“text”)
              tempPath = tempfile()
              writeBin(jsonlite::base64_dec(jsonlite::fromJSON(retrievedData)), tempPath)
             return(readRDS(tempPath))
         } else {
              return(jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(data,“text”)))  }
         }
```

Comment: I don't know much about firebase or R, but to store data in Google storage you need to specify the destination bucket (like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53886485/how-to-store-dataframe-data-to-firebase-storage)), I don't see where are you defining this bucket on the above code although I do see bucket definitions on other functions on the Git repo you shared, maybe you can verify the bucket you are using is correct and it exists inside your gcp project

Answer (score 0):

From what it sounds like, you are not using the correct R package. The Kohze/fireData package is used for uploading the firebase realtime database, not the firebase storage. For uploading text files to the firebase storage, you'd need to use the  paulsp94/fireData package (kinda confusing as both are fireData haha). The package can be found at https://github.com/paulsp94/fireData